# Short way to eliminate a list from a matrix, if the first element is negative

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I'm looking for a short way to eliminate a list from a matrix, if the first element of the list is negative. I've come up with this:

```
a = {{5, -1, 3, -2}, {-4, -3, -3, -4}, {2, -1, 5, 5}}

f[x_] := Table[x, 4];
Pick[a, f /@ UnitStep[a[[All, 1]]], 1] /. {} -> Nothing
```

The output is and should be:

```
{{5, -1, 3, -2}, {2, -1, 5, 5}}
```

In my example, all lists have a length of 4, this explains the `Table[x, 4]`. A general case would be more interesting.

Comment: `Select[a,#[[1]] >= 0&]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pick[a,#>=0&@@@a]
```

> `{{5, -1, 3, -2}, {2, -1, 5, 5}}`