# Create new pair list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose we have the following sample data:

```
data={{1,1},{2,1},{2,2},{2,3},{3,3},{4,3},{4,4},{5,4},{6,4},{7,4}}
```

I want remove pairs started with Even numers - {2,1},{2,2},{2,3},{4,3},{4,4},{6,4} 
How can I create a new pairs list containing on the first place increments of 1, The second value of pair of numbers remains unchanged

In other words how can I get this?

```
result={{1,1},{2,3},{3,4},{4,4}}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Similar questions were closed ([143738](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143738/5478), [139580](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139580/5478), [114709](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114709/5478)) but I managed to find a close enough duplicate. Just use `OddQ/EvenQ` in the test instead of `<20`.

Comment: Thanks You Kuba. I make this: Odd = Cases[data, {_?OddQ, _}][[All, 2]] and second command: Transpose[{Range[First[Dimensions[Odd]]], Odd}]